# P-value for point biserial correlation in R

Tags: r, correlation, p-value

Does anybody know of an R package that produces a p-value for point biserial correlations?

I've tried all of the major packages that I know (with some help from Google) and haven't found any. If a package doesn't come to mind, is there some way that I can intuitively calculate the p-value?

Answer (score 7):

The [point-biserial correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-biserial_correlation_coefficient) is equivalent to calculating the Pearson correlation between a continuous and a dichotomous variable (the latter needs to be encoded with 0 and 1). Therefore, you can just use the standard `cor.test` function in R, which will output the correlation, a 95% confidence interval, and an independent *t*-test with associated *p*-value:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- sample.int(100, 50, replace=TRUE)
y <- sample(c(0, 1), 50, replace=TRUE)
cor.test(x, y)
```

This yields a correlation of $r = 0.202$, which is not significant ($t = 1.429$, $\text{df} = 48$, $p = 0.1595$):

```
    Pearson's product-moment correlation

data:  x and y
t = 1.429, df = 48, p-value = 0.1595
alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.08088534  0.45478598
sample estimates:
      cor 
0.2020105
```

As @sal-mangiafico and @igor-p point out, the function `biserial.cor` from the `ltm` package produces slightly different results. This is because `cor.test` uses the population standard deviation, whereas `biserial.cor` uses the sample standard deviation. Furthermore, the result of `biserial.cor` has the opposite sign than the result of `cor.test`. This can be adjusted by specifying the argument `level=2` in `biserial.cor`.

Answer (score 2):

In response to @user9413061,

I think I discovered the source of the problem.

In the [standard definition of biserial correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-biserial_correlation_coefficient), the population standard deviation is used.

`ltm::biserial.cor` uses the sample standard deviation.

In the following, a function is defined to calculate the population standard deviation.  The function `biserial.cor.new` is defined, which is the same as `ltm::biserial.cor` with `sd.pop` used instead of `sd`.

I think `biserial.cor.new` will return the same result as `cor.test`.

```
sd.pop = function(x){sd(x)*sqrt((length(x)-1)/length(x))}

biserial.cor.new = 
function (x, y, use = c("all.obs", "complete.obs"), level = 1) 
{
    if (!is.numeric(x)) 
        stop("'x' must be a numeric variable.\n")
    y <- as.factor(y)
    if (length(levs <- levels(y)) > 2) 
        stop("'y' must be a dichotomous variable.\n")
    if (length(x) != length(y)) 
        stop("'x' and 'y' do not have the same length")
    use <- match.arg(use)
    if (use == "complete.obs") {
        cc.ind <- complete.cases(x, y)
        x <- x[cc.ind]
        y <- y[cc.ind]
    }
    ind <- y == levs[level]
    diff.mu <- mean(x[ind]) - mean(x[!ind])
    prob <- mean(ind)
    diff.mu * sqrt(prob * (1 - prob))/sd.pop(x)
}
```

And an example:

```
x = c(3,4,5,6,7,5,6,7,8,9)
y = c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1)

library(ltm)

### DIFFERENT RESULTS WITH ltm::biserial.cor

biserial.cor(x,y, level=2)

   ### [1] 0.5477226

cor.test(x,y)

   ### Pearson's product-moment correlation
   ### sample estimates:
   ###       cor 
   ### 0.5773503

### SAME RESULTS WITH new function

biserial.cor.new(x,y, level=2)

    ### [1] 0.5773503

cor.test(x,y)

   ### Pearson's product-moment correlation
   ### sample estimates:
   ###       cor 
   ### 0.5773503
```

Answer (score 1):

For my understanding you don't have to code the dichotome variable with 0 and 1. Therefore using other values results in exactly the same output. Try for example:

```
x <- 1:100
y <- rep(c(0,1), 50)
y2 <- rep(c(-786,345), 50)
cor.test(x, y)
cor.test(x, y2)
```

Both gives you an r of 0.01732137. The only thing that can happen by coding the dichotome variable differently is that you get -0.01732137, which will be the case if the first number is bigger than the second, e.g.

```
y3 <- rep(c(0,1), 50)
cor.test(x, y3)
```

results in -0.01732137.

Furthermore, I read on different pages that "the point-biserial correlation is equivalent to calculating the Pearson correlation between a continuous and a dichotomous variable", but in fact I get different results if I conduct a Pearson and a point-biserial correlation on same data.
An example:

```
x <- 1:100
y <- rep(c(0,1), 50)

cor.test(x, y)
```

gives me 0.01732137, but
`biserial.cor(x, y)` results in -0.01723455.

I understand that it is okay to get positive and negative values, but the absolute value should be the same, which is not the case. The results are also different if I use other data, e.g. `x <- rnorm(100, 100, 15)` instead of `x <- 1:100`.

For this reason I am unsure whether it is acceptable to use `cor.test()` and report that you have conducted a point-biserial correlation.

Comment: Please state, which package you take `biserial.cor` from. I guess, it's the `ltm` package, but who knows.  So the correlation is `0.017` in both cases, the rest probably some rounding error? If one function was superior, how do you know, which?

Comment: It appears that `ltm::biserial.cor` and `stats::cor.test` do not produce the same result. See `?ltm::biserial.cor` for the formula used there.

Comment: Yes, I used the ltm package.